# Plone: how generate RSS from a custom view / indexes

Tags: plone

I made some archetypes with indexes in the catalog and made views to show results. 
I want to "show" this results also a Rss feed. How to make it?

Advices? Inspiring source code?

Thank's

Vito

Comment: Collections and Folders have nice RSS support in Plone 4.3 so it should more or less just "work", although I think you might need to enable it in the control panel.

Comment: Thank's Lennart, but I'm on a 4.2 and I need several feeds "filtered" by different parameters, more or less 30 variations of the same RSS... I cannot figure out to made 30 different collections :(

Comment: Then you just need to make a view that generates the RSS you want.

Comment: Found an interesting page http://developer.plone.org/functionality/syndication.html